# How do we migrate "on hold" to "closed"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions

I'm not sure where to ask this since it is applicable to all sites, but I believe we need a way to migrate "on hold" to "closed". I'm encountering questions that are clearly not redeemable - usually because they are fundamentally about a subject that is off topic. I believe that these should be closed and not "on hold". However as things stand they can only be made "on hold".

The other case I have found is a question that is put "on hold" because it is vague, but is later found to be a duplicate. These should be closed and not "on hold".

How do we do this?

Answer (score 7):

We don't need to do anything. From [the StackExchange blog entry on the new changes made to the close vote system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/):

> Questions **not re-opened within five days** will revert to displaying as
>   “closed,” to serve as a clearer signpost going forward.